# Not receiving requested data from AccuWeather Weather Data Oracle

Tags: remix, chainlink, kovan, goerli

I'm attempting to pull weather data from the AccuWeather Weather Data Oracle (https://market.link/nodes/AccuWeather/integrations) through the Goerli Testnet. I've funded my contract with enough LINK to make a request to the Operator Address: 0xB9756312523826A566e222a34793E414A81c88E1 as well as designated the specId, callbackAddr, and the callbackFunctionSignature in the buildChainlinkRequest() function. Essentially, I've followed every step of the Example Consumer Contract provided by AccuWeather. However, oracle data that I'm requesting is not returned to the designated callbackFunctionSignature. Has someone run into a similar problem when working with the AccuWeather Weather Data Oracle Node? If so, is there a way to troubleshoot this Request-Receive cycle issue? Thank you so much!

One thing to add is that the Request-Receive cycle was working on the Kovan Testnet as I was able to get weather condition data back. So I'm really confused why it would be different on the Goerli Testnet. Appreciate any insight or thoughts on this issue.